# Is there a way to retrieve the "level" passed to error() from xpcall's message handler?

Tags: lua

When using `xpcall` with a message handler, that message handler is able to view the error string produced by Lua, and is also able to inspect the call stack at the time of the error.

For example:

```lua
function somethingBad()
  error("Something bad happened", 3)
end

function doSomething()
  somethingBad()
end

function doAThing()
  doSomething()
end
```

calling `doAThing` via `xpcall` with a message handler, inside the message handler we can pop the top of the stack to give us something like:
`[string "function somethingBad()..."]:10 Something bad happened`

As we can see, that Lua has internally already taken the `level` parameter into account, giving a line `10` in the message, rather than line `2`.

However, it seems that this `level` parameter (`3`) is no longer in the stack by the time that `xpcall`'s message handler is invoked. It would be really useful however if we could recover it, so that we can do something like

```
lua_Debug ar;
lua_getstack(L, level, &ar);
lua_getinfo(L, "nSl", &ar);
```

inside the message handler.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance

Note:
My investigations so far have shown that calling `error("msg", level)` from lua triggers the `luaB_error` C function. I believe it is this function which uses the `level` parameter to adjust the error string produced. I think once it has done this, it somehow removes the `level` parameter from the stack, so that by the time we end up in the message handler we no longer have this parameter available.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't know exactly how you plan to use this parameter, since it is something you can control, you can encode it into your error message.

```
error({msg = "Something bad happened", level = 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the luaB_error function:

```c
static int luaB_error (lua_State *L) {
  int level = (int)luaL_optinteger(L, 2, 1);
  lua_settop(L, 1);
  if (lua_type(L, 1) == LUA_TSTRING && level > 0) {
    luaL_where(L, level);   /* add extra information */
    lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
    lua_concat(L, 2);
  }
  return lua_error(L);
}
```

> I think once it has done this, it somehow removes the level parameter from the stack

You are correct. It's `lua_settop(L, 1);` that does this. So unfortunately, this is indeed not possible.